# Objective-c serialized dictionary with node js server

Tags: objective-c, json, node.js, nsdictionary

I have a serialized `NSDictionary` (in fact, it's an inapp purchase receipt) which I send to `node.js` server:

```
{ "key 1" = "val 1";
  "key 2" = "val 2"; }
```

I want to deserialize it on a server side, so that's what I've done so far:

```
var jsonStr = dictStr.replace(/"\s*=\s*"/g, "\":\"").replace(/";\s/g,"\",").replace(/,\s*}/,"}");
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
```

Code above works just fine, but of course I'm worrying if I took into account all possible cases. That's why I'd prefer to have a real parser for obj-c `NSDictionary` format.

May be someone could recommend me one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A serialised `NSDictionary` looks to me to be almost JSON, in fact, it's so close to being json that I made a simple parser (using [jison](https://github.com/zaach/jison)) that parses a serialised `NSDictionary` to a JSON string. You can check it out [here](https://github.com/Loknar/parser-NSDictionary-to-JSON).

Comment: @Loknar I'm getting an error trying to parse the keys. "Expecting 'STRINGVALUE', got 'STRING'". It seems it's expecting the NSDictionary to be in the format {key = "val"}, instead of {"key" = "val"}.

Comment: hi @pyetti, NSDictionary might have been redefined, idunno, when I was fiddling around with it 5 years back {key1 = "val"; key2 = "val"} was how NSDictionary looked, see parseExample1.txt but if you want {"key1" = "val"; "key2" = "val"} instead you only need to edit one line in the bison definition in parser.jison, keyname should then be STRING instead of STRINGVALUE, see https://github.com/Loknar/parser-NSDictionary-to-JSON/blob/master/parser.jison#L95-L96 hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @Loknar. I'll try it out. For now, I've been using the OPs original Regex and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

Try [JSONkit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit). There is [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html), but I think JSONKit has still proven to be faster.

Comment: I thought about serializing to JSON on a client side, but first I want to make sure that I can't do it on node.js side.

Comment: You could try to get an `NSData` object from the dictionary using `NSKeyedArchiver` and send that through, then decode. If you are just sending a trivial JSON string, that might be overkill though.

Comment: I'm sending what I get from Apple's inapp purchases server - NSDictionary string (see example in the question) encoded with base64. What I want to know if there's any parsers that allows to parse this format (which is not JSON) in JavaScript.